# How to avoid hitting rate limits using twitter REST API in my ruby follower scraper

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

I'm keep hitting "Rate limit exceeded TooManyRequests" error in my ruby twitter follower scraper. I have tried adding "sleep", like this

```
def my_userarray(users)
  userarray = []
  users.each do |user|
    userarray << user.screen_name
sleep 3
  end
  return userarray
end
```

but it does not work. Either it takes extremely long time, or I hit limit. I'm getting this error even with small number of followers, like 8000. I have also tried adding this:

```
puts "sleeping 60"
sleep 60
```

to https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb
but it also does not work. These were the only solutions I could find searching it for whole day. Thanks for any help.

This is how my code looks now:

```
def my_usernames
 "detnewsRodBeard"
end

def my_userinfo(names)
  @client.followers(names)
end

def my_userarray(users)
  userarray = []
  users.each do |user|
    userarray << user.screen_name

  end
  return userarray
end

def my_users
 my_userarray(my_userinfo(my_usernames))
end

def my_csv(my_users)
  CSV.open('./my_users.csv','a+') do |csv|
    my_users.each do |k,v|
      csv << [k,v]
    end
  end
end

my_csv(my_users)
```

Comment: link is dead. Also `followers` will be a single request for the specified user and will return a list limited to 20 users you would then need to use the next_cursor to navigate so 8000 followers would result in 400 requests. The `/followers` endpoint  is limited to 15 Requests per 15 minute window (30 if using app auth) by the Twitter API. Is there a reason you are trying to do this an if so 8000 followers will take you ~ 6.7 hours (3.3 hours using app_auth) to aggregate in this fashion. [Twitter REST API /followers/list](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list)

Comment: yeah but with one request you should get 5000 users, si it should take like 2 minutes max.

Comment: Where did you get the idea of 5000 users? Twitter Docs say 20. Although this is scalable to 200 so I guess you could get 8000 done in ~40 minutes. given you pass the count option to be 200 on every request.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600103/ruby-twitter-gem-rate-limit-exceeded but also others, people are able to scrape millions, so I doubt they are doing it by 20. Also i can scrape few hundred in just seconds, but i need scrape at least hundreds of thousands in few hours.

Comment: 5000 is for the ids only not the users themselves. [Twitter Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids) is very helpful and explicit

Comment: But I have found this in twitter gem documentation, could it be used somehow? http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/RateLimit

Comment: Ok now i see you were right, so i had error in my code all the time :) thanks al ot for help

Comment: So i replaced @client.followers(names) with @client.follower_ids(names), but that gives me errors. Any idea how to replace it correctly? thanks

Comment: Ok i found the solutions altering this code https://gist.github.com/sferik/9630519, but thanks for pointing me in right direction :)